# How to Pass string value as parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

This is my code:

```
    var Area = "000000002";
    <a class='button orange' id='proceed' onclick='testFunction("+Area+")' href='javascript:;'>Proceed</a>
```

Now when this value is sent to the next function i.e ....

```
    function testFunction(Area)
    {
    alert(Area)
    }
```

In this case I get the value 2....what i should be getting is 000000002....

So i guess it is not being sent as a string.

I need to know how to get the value 000000002 is the testFunction...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var Area = "000000002";
<a class='button orange' id='proceed' onclick='testFunction(&apos;"+Area+"&apos;)' href='javascript:;'>Proceed</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to do this "+Area+";

```
function testFunction(Area)
{
    alert(Area.toString())
}
var Area = "000000002";

<a class='button orange' id='proceed' onclick='testFunction(Area)' href='javascript:;'>Proceed</a>
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score -1):

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" onclick="myFunction(<%=ppiid+","+price+","+"'"+pname+"'"%>)">add to cart</button> 

 function myFunction(x,y,z)
     {        
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x+" "+y+" "+z.toString();             
     }

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Format the Answer Properly other wise you will get more down votes